# Disable Narrator.exe in windows 8 and above

Tags: windows, file-permissions, icacls

The Narrator is one annoying windows feature and i wanted to get rid of it.

So i decided to change the file permissions. I took ownership of the Narrator.exe which was located in the Windows System directory and used **icacls** to deny the execution of this file.

```
takeown /f %windir%\system32\Narrator.exe

icacls %windir%\system32\Narrator.exe /deny *S-1-1-0:(RX)
```

It worked and the user was not able to launch narrator by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys.

The problem started when a user clisked <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. It invoked narrator. And since then, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> also invoked narrator.

Can anyone help me understand how <kbd>**Win**</kbd> + <kbd>**L**</kbd> altered the behavior ?

Comment: WIN + L should have just locked the system. That is interesting Behavior.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin , i have actually disabled that feature as well :p But Win + L is now playing with the file access permissions .. and i am not able to undestand how.

Comment: Hmmm. Im wondering if the computer is still thinking it is locked thus Narrator.exe would be active from the lock screen. Change the .exe to .txt and it wont activate anymore.